# Временное хранение данных и работа с ними в Android, как сделать?

Tags: java, android

Нужно при запуске приложения получить массив данных типа int, возможно и byte и работать с ними, после закрытия приложения данные должно уничтожатся.

Как такое можно организовать, стандартными методами в Android 4.X и выше

Comment: Так запили их в переменую, уборщик мусора подберет их когда нужно.

Comment: @nekaneka Вариант, чуть позже попробую, а то что то я туплю уже